# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown in Jade Not Rendering Correctly

Tags: html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I can't figure out how to render the simple dropdown menu in Bootstrap's navbar in Jade. Trying to render this HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

in Jade like this:

```
li.dropdown
a.dropdown-toggle(data-toggle="dropdown", role="button", aria-haspopup="true", aria-expanded="false"): span.caret Tools
    li
        a(href="#") action
    li 
        a(href="#") another action
```

According to the http://jade-lang.com/reference/tags/ you should be able to nest tags like:

```
 a: span
```

But when I try to add classes to those tags it looks crazy weird [http://codepen.io/thehumanscience/pen/qbLepW](http://codepen.io/thehumanscience/pen/qbLepW?editors=1000):

Anyone know how to do this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the : shorthand and nest at same time.  You'd need to:

```
li.dropdown
  a.dropdown-toggle(data-toggle="dropdown")
    | Dropdown
    span.caret
  ul.dropdown-menu
    li
      a(href="#") action
    li 
      a(href="#") another action
```

Comment: Thanks! This works nicely. My problem is I still don't understand why it works. According to http://jade-lang.com/reference/tags/ :shortand and nesting seem to be the same thing. "To save space, jade provides an inline syntax for nested tags. 'a: img is how you nest <a><img></a>. I see the explanation for using the | (pipe symbol) here http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/ but I don't think they explain it very...not for a newbie to Jade like me.

Comment: I think the problem you are seeing is due to `span.caret Tools` not the nesting - note that this results in `<span class="caret">Tools</span>` not `<span class="caret"></span> Tools`.    AFAIK there's no way to separate the .caret and Tools into separate tags using the : shorthand